# Creating new Json object in java vs using JSON object from redis

Tags: java, json, performance

Few unchanged data (for ex. asset details of a user) available in HttpServletRequest object. I want to set these value to a API response. Which one is the best way? How?

1. Getting data from HttpServletRequest and construct JSON object for Response
2. Store JSON response in Redis and use these JSONObject for API Response

Answer (score 0):

Since this is tagged [performance](/questions/tagged/performance)... option 1 will be faster since it doesn't involve any external calls.

However fast Redis might be, reading from `HttpServletRequest` directly will always be faster.